# ingress-nginx allow-backend-server-header not working as expected

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

The kubernetes `ingress-nginx` controller adds (or replaces) the `server` response header by default.

My understanding is that the option `allow-backend-server-header` was added to pass the default server header through to the client.

Installing with helm:

```sh
helm install stable/nginx-ingress \
--namespace ingress-basic \
--set controller.config.allow-backend-server-header="true"
```

But when I hit my server with nginx in front of it, I am still getting `server: openresty/1.15.8.1` in my response headers, when I expect either nothing, or something different.

Am I missing something or is this supposed to work differently than I'm expecting it to?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

By default Nginx Ingress will add a header like `Server: nginx/1.17.10`. If you set

```sh
controller.config.allow-backend-server-header="true"
```

it will allow the `Server` header from backend server to pass through to client. So I guess you are using openresty as a backend server and hence you are seeing it in the `Server` header.